# Handle datetime timestamp javascript(angularjs) and mongo for slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I'm using angularjs and mongodb.

I have not found a angularjs date slider so I'm taking [this one](http://prajwalkman.github.io/angular-slider/). The idea is to use a timestamp with a step a day. So I take this timestamp convert it to a `dd mmmm yyyy` format and be displayed in the front-end.

Assuming as I said I use mongodb what can be a good solution for the date number format?

Comment: Something unambiguous and easy to read such as 15-Nov-2013 would suit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a date time library, try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

It is very simple to use. Include the script file using `<script>` tag. Then use it like this.

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
```

This will return **November 6th 2013, 1:35:00 pm**

If you need to show the time in human format use `fromNow()` like this `moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();` This will result **2 years ago** .